# CSS :hover - How to make :hover on text affect an image?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a navigation menu done with images, and I have animated a mouse over glow effect on the images using CSS transitions and opacity. For SEO purposes, I want the navigation menu to include text links.

The glow effect is done using CSS `background-image` and html foreground images. On mouse over the opacity of the foreground image slowly goes to 0 revealing the background image underneath.

I have worked out how to position the text over the images, using `position:relative` for the parent `div` and `position:absolute` for the `p`. But when the mouse hovers over the text, it is no longer counted as hovering over the image, because the text is on top of the image. As a result, the glow effect doesn't work.

In flash it's pretty easy to make mouse over on one object cause changes in another object. Is there any way to do this in CSS? If not then can javascript do what I need?

**Edit**

Thanks for the replys. Here is the code. Apologies if it's messy, I haven't done any HTML coding in years, and have never worked with CSS before.

**I have only put text and a link on the first button so far.**

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.htm"><p class="homebutton">HOME</p><img class="navbutton" src="_images/home-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Home Button" title="Home" height="115" width="120" /></a></li>
    <li><img class="navbutton" src="_images/how-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. How To Use Our Services Button" title="How To Use Our Services" height="115" width="120" /></li>
    <li><img class="navbutton" src="_images/playstation-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Playstation Repair Button" title="Playstation Repair" height="115" width="120" /></li>
    <li><img class="navbutton" src="_images/xbox-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Xbox Repair Button" title="Xbox Repair" height="115" width="120" /></li>
    <li><img class="navbutton" src="_images/wii-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Wii Repair Button" title="Wii Repair" height="115" width="120" /></li>
    <li><img class="navbutton" src="_images/reviews-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Customer Reviews Button" title="Customer Reviews" height="115" width="120" /></li>
    <li><img class="navbutton" src="_images/map-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Location And Map Button" title="Location and Map" height="115" width="120" /></li>
    <li><img class="navbutton" src="_images/contact-button.png" alt="Website Navigation. Contact Us Button" title="Contact Us" height="115" width="120" /></li>
  </ul>

<!-- end .nav --></div>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
  background-image: url(../_images/nav-bg.png);
  width:960px;
  height:115px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  position:relative;
}

.navbutton {
  -webkit-transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transition:opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  float:left;
}

img.navbutton:hover {
  opacity:0;
}      

.homebutton {
  position:absolute;
  left:19px;
  top:70px;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok I have created a fiddle to make it easier to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/sK5q2/

As you can see the image does not fade when the mouse is over the text

Comment: Hi Chris, it would be real helpful for you to post your CSS/HTML.  It would be even more if you simply put it in "fiddle" (http://jsfiddle.net/). By doing that, SO members can easily look at your code and adjust as needed for you and help point out any issues.

Comment: Here in SO we use to paste html and CSS - and in questions having to do with L&F also a JSFIDDLE or Tinkerbin or Liveweave link. It's hard for someone to "imagine" your problem by reading plain text..

Comment: if your grouping DIV element contains both the P element and the image – then why don’t you just apply your formatting on :hovering over the DIV element …?

Comment: @CBrow - Wouldn't I need a separate DIV for each button then? I would rather keep them all in the same DIV if possible

Comment: Also I think the text would with fade out with the button then

Comment: Ok I have created a fiddle to make it easier to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/sK5q2/

Comment: As you can see the image does not fade when the mouse is over the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your updated question and fiddle (thanks for the fiddle!) here's a fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/sK5q2/1/

It was as easy as simply adjusting your CSS selector as such:

Change: `img.navbutton:hover {`

To: `a:hover img.navbutton {`

I'll try to explain but probably do a bad job at it. ;)

If elements are siblings such as...

```
<img />
<p>Text</p>
```

... you can reposition them however you like with styles, but they're pretty much independent of each other.  While your CSS styles did place one on top of the other, it's purely visual, not so much technical.  Moving the mouse over the text appears as if you moved from the `<img/>` element and onto the `<p/>` element.

If you see the HTML above, think of that layout as your mouse touches the visual image.  The `<img/>` would highlight in the code.  If you then touch the text, the `<p/>` would highlight, which is a different element.

Now, if you wrap that in a link...

```
<a>
    <img />
    <p>Text</p>
</a>
```

... and you're targeting the link as the hot spot for the `:hover`, you're always touching the link hot spot regardless if the mouse is *also touching* the `<img/>` *or* `<p/>` tag.

In this sense, if you're touching the image, the `<a/>` tag will be highlighted as well as the `<img/>` element.  If you move to the text the `<a/>` tag will still be highlighted but now the `<p/>` element is highlighted.

The thing is, our CSS style is targeting the "always touched" element `<a/>`.

Sorry, that was harder to explain than I thought.  Hopefully that helps! =)

Cheers!

---

.. Original Post ..

---

I've got a feeling your real problem is simply a CSS issue, but I created a proof-of-concept fiddle based on what you are describing:

http://jsfiddle.net/7rU7L/

The concept is a standard horizontal "tab" list with styles taken directly from Dan Cedarholm's CSS/HTML patterns site pea.rs (http://pea.rs/navigation/horizontal-tabs)

```
<li id="a"><a href="#"><img /><b>Ahy!</b></a></li>
```

The concept is that you have a link that has an image inside along with some text.  In this case, I used the `<img />` tag and simply styled them with a red background and a fixed width/height.

I then absolutely positioned the `<b/>` tag over the image.

On hover, I adjust the `<b/>` tag's left position (instead of, say, the color).

(*I abbreviated the code in this example for simplicity*)

```
li a:hover b{
    left:45px;
}
```

You simply target the parent `<a>` tag with the `:hover` pseudo-class and select the child element (in this case `<b/>`) you want to style.

However, I have a feeling there's more funky things going on with your CSS/HTML, but this is to show that you can do what you're looking for (change the styles on a child element of a link).

If you post your real code, I can look over it and adjust my answer.

I hope that helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Ok I have created fiddle to make it easier to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/sK5q2/

Comment: As you can see the image does not fade when the mouse is over the text

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the fiddle!  The problem appears to be the issue is the :hover is on the `<img/>` not the `<a/>`.  It is correct that the img doesn't fade when over the text.  If you move the `:hover` to trigger on the parent `<a/>` that should work.  I'm playing around with your fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sK5q2/1/  Boy, that was a lot easier than I figured.  It's as simple as changing your selector as such: `img.navbutton:hover {` to => `a:hover img.navbutton {`

Comment: Glad it worked!  To accept this as an answer, please click the check mark under the up/down vote so your question can be marked answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with something like this?:

```
.textThatIwantToHover:hover, .imageThatIwantToAffect:hover{
    //some css
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make the text fade out aswell as the image?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Without the comma had no effect at all. With the comma just caused the text to disappear, and had no effect on the image.

Comment: Ok I have created a fiddle to make it easier to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/sK5q2/

Comment: As you can see the image does not fade when to mouse is over the text